# Problem in understanding Regularized Cost Function for neural neworks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization

I am having difficulty in understanding the cost function  equation for neural nets described in andrew ng's coursera class. The equation is as follows :-

[image]

I am having difficulty in interpreting the regularization term. What does the 3 summations signify. I hope someone can break up the problem and help me understand the equation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first term looks a normal *cross-entropy* loss function.

The second term is a regularization term. It increases the cost function to "punish" large values for weights. It's called **L2 weight-decay** (L2 means it's using the square value, L1 means absolute value). This is done to prevent overfitting, because it makes it more difficult for the network to learn *noise* from input samples.

Now for the formula: (note that the formula is for a whole batch of `m` input samples).

The summation symbol is just another way of writing a **for-loop** so what the three summations means is this: **for each layer `l` and for every pair of connecting units `i` and `j`, take the square of the weight from `j` to `i`, then add everything**.

The lambda parameter is just used to control how much regularization you want; a large lambda means you want you want your network to be very regularized, a small lambda means you just want a little bit of regularization.

Comment: What exactly does i and j represent? And why is i looping till sl and j looping till (sl + 1)?

Comment: `i` and `j` are hidden units. `l` is the layer index. From zero to (number of layers - 1). I think `s_l` is the number of units on layer `l`.

Comment: To be more precise ,  i want to know **why** is i looping till s_l and j till (s_l + 1) ? There must be a reason i guess.

Comment: Because you want to **add** all weights from layer `l` to layer `l + 1`, so you need `s_l` times `s_l +1` weights, because it's a fully connected layer.

Comment: Sorry , but I still didn't quite get it. What  does a "fully connected layer" mean? Also , does i represent the previous layer  and j the current hidden layer or vice- versa. I'm a relatively new in machine learning , so please try to explain in layman terms :)

Comment: A fully-connected layer means that **all** units in a layer have connections (weights) to **all** units in the next layer.

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark it as solved =)

Comment: Maked as solved ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late, but better late than never (at least for instructional purposes). Here is an example of a nn setup:

[image: Neural Network setup]

Here is the regularization term:

[image: Regularization term]

See how a nn theta matrix is arrayed:

[image: Weights matrix]

You can see that in any theta, the superscript "l" is the layer of "causing" units, and the two subscripts identify the activation unit in "l+1" and the "causing" unit in "l", respectively. Therefore, in the nn setup above, for example:

[image]

this is the theta that maps from unit x(1) in layer 1 to activation unit a(2) in layer 2. As you can see the second subscript is associated to the "causing" layer (l) and therefore its loop goes from 1 to s(1) (which is the last unit in layer 1 in the above setup, and is called s_subscript_"l" in the J function). The first subscript is associated to the activation unit in layer l+1 (the "caused" layer) and therefore its loop goes from 1 to s(2) (which is the last unit in layer 2 in the above setup, and is called s_subscript_"l+1" in the J function).

With that I hope the "i" and "j" loops get more intuitive now.